Can't integrate localization and navigation in my launch file
I am studying Ros2 for a college project, I've build this robot using some tutorials to help me. I am now researching how to make a dynamic navigation node. My problem is, everytime I run my robot, I also have to run rviz, localization and navigation. So I was modifying my launch file and encountered an error.

Here is the code of my launch file:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node



def generate_launch_description():


    package_name='my_bot'
    
    config_dir = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config')
    map_file = os.path.join(config_dir,'casaMapa_save.yaml')
    rviz_config_dir = os.path.join(config_dir,'navigation.rviz')

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
    )

    # Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
             )

    # Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                   '-entity', 'my_bot'],
                        output='screen')

    localization = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','localization_launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments=[{'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items(), {'map' : map_file}]
    )
    
    navigation = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','navigation_launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments=[{'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items(), {'map_subscribe_transient_local' : 'true'}]
    )

    rviz = Node(package='rviz2',
                executable='rviz2',
                name='rviz2_node',
                arguments=['-d', rviz_config_dir],
                output='screen'
                )


    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
        rviz,
        localization,
        navigation,
    ])

Any help would be appreciated!

Please paste any console output as code formatted text, and not as screenshots. Images are not text searchable, amongst other things...

I think your error may be with the launch_argments in the rsp section. In the other sections launch_arguments has 2 tuples, while rsp only has one. This would explain the "not enough variables to unpack, expected 2 but got 1" error

No, it didn't solve it. Actually, when i just comment localization and navigation in return LaunchDescription it still partially works, but when i tried putting a tuple as an input for rsp i got the same error as before
